# Form position VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a two form app.. The main form loads to the bottom corner of the screen. But I am having trouble making the second form load in the center of that form all times. I used to do the parent/child thing but it screws up my design a bit. Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks!

```
'Set window to lower right of screen
    Me.Location = New Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the child form is a dialog form, then all you have to do is set the StartPosition property:

```
Dim f As New Form
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
f.ShowDialog(Me)
```

If the child form is not a dialog form, then try positioning the form manually:

```
Dim f As New Form
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
AddHandler f.Load, Sub()
                     f.Location = New Point(Me.Left + Me.Width / 2 - f.Width / 2, _
                                            Me.Top + Me.Height / 2 - f.Height / 2)
                   End Sub
f.Show(Me)
```

Comment: Use the Load event instead so the move isn't visible.  The form is already rescaled by then.

Comment: Ok, I tried this but it loads the second form to the top left corner of the first form now. How to Center it?

Comment: @CJSoldier Which snippet are your referring to?  You have to tell me what you are doing differently than what I posted, including *when* you are calling the code.

Comment: @LarsTech Ok... sorry bout that. I added this {Me.Location = New Point(Form1.Left + Form1.Width / 2 - Form1.Width / 2, Form1.Top + Form1.Height / 2 - Form1.Height / 2)} to the Load event on my second form.

Comment: @CJSoldier You are calling `Form1.Width / 2` twice.  The second one should be the `Me.Width / 2`.

Comment: @LarsTech AH... yeah I copied incorrectly. That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second form to be centered in the first one, you should apply this formula :

```
Me.Location = New Point((firstForm.Width - Me.Width) / 2, (firstForm.Height - Me.Height) / 2)
```

Comment: Well that brought it down to the middle of the screen but not the middle of the form. It shows up to the left of the screen.

Comment: Didn't you forget to change `Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width` by `yourFirstForm.Width` (and Height of course) ?

Comment: I am not understanding your comment. I changed the yourFirstForm.Width/Height to the form name and placed it into the load event on the form needing to be in the center of the already open form.